# Нужно сделать элементы как на фото

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Хочу сделать элементы как на фото, а они встают друг за другом :( Знаю что inline нужно использовать, но как именно не понимаю [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<div class="community">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">       
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h2>Community Sign Up</h2>

                    <i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i>
                    <h3>Signup process</h3>
                    <p><br>1. User enters email address <br> 2. Clicks on "Sign up for free"</p>
                    <div class="soc_icons">
                        <i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-chain-broken"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: какие элементы ??

Comment: i,h3, p как на фото

Comment: http://codepen.io/Geyan/full/ObBRWV/  так ??

Comment: @Geyan  Да, только иконку чуть больше, но суть верна)

Comment: я сделал - а стальное сам